# BigQuery job already exists

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In one of our GCP project multiple bigquery scheduled  queries are running but recently we started facing failing job issue with the following error -

> Error Message: Already Exists: Job <PROJECT ID>:US.scheduled_query_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx; JobID:<PROJECT NUMBER>:scheduled_query_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

The write preference of these queries is "WRITE_APPEND". These jobs were created using GCP console.

Once retriggered these jobs run successfully with a new job ID.
Please help in understanding the reason behind used job ID allocation to these scheduled queries and please suggest if any fix available.

Comment: Can you share the piece of your code where you create your BQ job? And do you let the API generated this job ID or do you generate it in your code?

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, we have not used any script to create these scheduled queries. These have been created using GCP console.

Comment: Check for any scheduled  jobs list on BQ UI if they are still running/scheduled. Or may be check the big-query slots in your Org

Comment: Hi @Prany, currently we have not reserved any BQ slots, the jobs are running using on-demand slot model. 
There are multiple scheduled queries in the project. When we got that error, checked with the job ID mentioned  in the error message and found that job ID was already assigned to a successful scheduled query(not the same query for which we got the error).